# Scala: error: not found: value MutableList val ReviewsList = MutableList [Review]()

Tags: scala, mutablelist

I have trouble with the code below:

```scala
class Review(label: Double, features:org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector)

def transformDataTFIDF(plainText: RDD[String],reviewClass:String,label:Int,numTerms:Int): org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Review] = {
  val lemmatized = plainText.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).mapPartitions(iter => {
    val pipeline = createNLPPipeline();
    iter.map{  case(id, contents) => (id.toString(),
      plainTextToLemmas(contents, stopWords, pipeline))
    };
  }).cache()
  val (termDocMatrix, termIds, docIds, idfs) = termDocumentMatrix(lemmatized, stopWords, numTerms, sc)
  val vectorizedReviewsMap = Map( reviewClass -> termDocMatrix)
  val ReviewsList = MutableList[Review]()
  val ReviewsVecRDD = vectorizedReviewsMap(reviewClass).collect().foreach(v => ReviewsList += Review(label,v.asML))
  ReviewsList.toDS()
}
```

I have gotten this error:

```
<console>:73: error: not found: value MutableList
       val ReviewsList = MutableList [Review]()
```

Can you tell what should I do to correct it ?

Comment: First, there is no `MutableList` in the stdlib, maybe it was `ListBuffer`? - Second, probably all you need to do is `import` it, but since we do not know which type it should be and from which library does it come then it is not possible to do that. - Third, there is no much point in using a distributed system like **Spark** if you are going to `collect` all the data into a local `List` to then distribute it again when you can just call `toDS` on the `RDD` directly. - Fourth, if you do not know how to fix an import error, nor why `collect` is bad, you should not be using **Spark**

Answer (score 2):

[`MutableList`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/MutableList.scala#L170) existed up to Scala 2.12. It was removed at Scala 2.13 You probably didn't import it. Try:

```
import scala.collection.mutable
val ReviewsList = mutable.MutableList[Review]()
```

Or:

```
val ReviewsList = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Review]()
```

Working code snippet at [Scala 2.12](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/5zZJag64RYCjVwM79JaJZg) and the same non working example for [Scala 2.13](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/fk5P0y5kTEW5pB6BpI2nKA).